# Saving interpolated function into a separate file in Julia

Tags: julia, interpolation

It is easy to save an array as files (such as .txt/.csv formats) in Julia/Python, but is there any way to save a function generated from interpolating an array? Taking a simple example:

```
using Interpolations

inter = Dict("constant" => BSpline(Constant()), 
    "linear" => BSpline(Linear()), 
    "quadratic" => BSpline(Quadratic(Line(OnCell()))),
    "cubic" => BSpline(Cubic(Line(OnCell())))
)

arr = rand(100, 100, 100)  # 3D array
func = interpolate(arr, inter["cubic"])
```

How can this function be saved for future use, such that one does not need to interpolate the function again each time when one runs the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use [JLD2](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl).

```
using JLD2
@save "savedfunction.jld" func
```

And then reload with

```
using Interpolations, JLD2
@load "savedfunction.jld"
func
```

Comment: I tried the exact same syntax, but as I loaded the function and called it, it gave me tons of warning,  something like `...(type) does not exist in workspace; reconstructing└ @ JLD2 C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\JLD2\w2vgv\src\data.jl:11581`, and then an error `MethodError: objects of type Array{Symbol,1} are not callable. Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.`

Comment: Did you do `using Interpolation` before `@load`? Otherwise, a type is reconstructed which matches the Interpolation function's memory layout, but it does not have the same behaviours. I've corrected the example code.